# Using a Powershell script to find a bitlocker value of TpmPin

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I need a PS script that will result with True or False depending if TpmPin exists within 'KeyProtector' (see attached pic)

I have tried:

```
$res3 = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C
if ($res3 -like 'Tpm'){write 'True'} else {write 'false'}
```

but always get 'false' even though the value is there. [see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZLI6.png)

I've tried some example snippets found elsewhere on this site and they work:

```
$coll = 'one','two','three','four'
if ($coll -contains 'two'){write 'True'} else {write 'false'}
```

this returns T/F as needed.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Try `if ($res3.KeyProtector -contains 'TpmPin')`

Comment: Thanks.... 
that didn't work but '-like' does...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this older post helped me after I did the following tweak - fyi.

```
$res3 = ((Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint "C:").KeyProtector.keyprotectortype)

if ($res3 -like 'TpmPin'){
    write 'True'
} else {
    write 'False'
}
```